# Trying to merge a picture into an OpenTBS template fails with "failed to found the picture" (sic)

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

Im using OpenTBS to merge data from PHP into a word template.

All the normal variables merge fine, however I fail to succeed at merging an image file.

The placeholder for my image in my Word file looks like this:

```
[onshow.logo;ope=changepic]
```

When running the PHP script, I always get

`TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: Parameter ope=changepic used in the field [onshow.logo] has failed to found the picture. The process is ending, unless you set NoErr property to true.`

I tried setting my php variable to the URL of the picture or to the absolute path of the picture on the server, both fail:

- https://path.to.my.picture/picture.jpg
- /var/drupal/platform/html/sites/default/files/2022-02/picture.jpg"

Is there anything obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default OpenTBS expects the TBS field to be placed after the picture.
You can tune this relative placement using parameter `tagpos`, so it can after, before or inside (in an image property).

More details ate the [documentation](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#pic).

Comment: So my problem was I did not realize I had to insert a picture into my word template at all - I thought I was just supposed to put the placeholder there. Thanks!

Comment: The other advantage of having the image already present is to be able to make adjustments to it (size, border, etc.)